# How to import data from a single .csv file and save it in three different tables by mentioning the specific columns

Tags: php, mysql, csv, wordpress

I am working on a plugin, it create a three different tables "wp_foo_songs", "wp_foo_playlist", "wp_foo_rating".

In plugin i make a feature that export data from these 3 tables in one .csv file, it export data successfully.

In plugin there is also a feature that import the data from .csv file. Now i want that when a user upload that csv file, the data stored in 3 tables with respectively columns. I write the different queries but i failed.

Here is my code:

Export Query:
$pre = $wpdb->prefix;

```
$query = "SELECT plist.*, psong.*, prate.* 
          FROM " . $pre . "foo_playlists As plist 
          LEFT JOIN " . $pre . "foo_songs As psong
          On plist.playlist_name = psong.splaylist_name 
          LEFT JOIN " . $pre . "foo_rating As prate
          On psong.song_id = prate.rsong_id";

 $result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$line = "";
$comma = "";
foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
    $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
    $comma = ",";
}
$line .= "\n";
$out = $line;
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $line = "";
    $comma = "";
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
        $comma = ",";
    }
    $line .= "\n";
    $out.=$line;
}
$csv_file_name = 'songs_' . date('Ymd_His') . '.csv'; # CSV FILE NAME WILL BE table_name_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.csv
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $csv_file_name);
header("Content-Description:File Transfer");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
echo __($out, "hmp");

exit;
```

It gives me the right result look like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deemi/xY92T/)

Import Query:

```
$fileName = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];

// Playlist Import Query
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $fileName . "' INTO TABLE `wp_foo_playlists`
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
         OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
         LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
         (@pcol1,@pcol2,@pcol3,@pcol4) 
         Set playlist_id=@pcol1,playlist_name=@pcol2,playlist_description=@pcol3,
         playlist_shortcode=@pcol4";
         $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Songs Import Query               
$query1 = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $fileName . "' INTO TABLE `wp_foo_songs`
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
         OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
         LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
         (@scol1,@scol2,@scol3,@scol4,@scol5,@scol6,@scol7,@scol8,@scol9,@scol10,
         @scol11,@scol12,@scol13,@scol14,@scol15,@scol16)
         Set song_id=@scol1,list_order=@scol2,splaylist_name=@scol3,mp3=@scol4,
         ogg=@scol5,title=@scol6,buy=@scol7,buyy=@scol8,buyyy=@scol9,price=@scol10,
         cover=@scol11,duration=@scol12,artist=@scol13,total_votes=@scol14,
         song_shortcode=@scol15,song_slug=@scol16";

         $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

// Rating Import Query
$query2 = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $fileName . "' INTO TABLE `wp_foo_rating`
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
         OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
         LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
         (@rcol1,@rcol2,@rcol3,@rcol4) 
         Set rate_id=@rcol1,rsong_id=@rcol2,rating_value=@rcol3,user_ip=@rcol4";
         $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
```

It store the first table data correctly, but in two tables it save the first table data again and then save another data.

Any one please help i have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i get answer by my own.

I am using "fgetcsv" instead of "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE"

Here is my code:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
            // echo "File " . $_FILES['filename']['name'] . " uploaded successfully." . "";
            // echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
            // readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);


            $fileName = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];

            //$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(preg_match("/\.(csv)$/", $fileName)){
                die("Please upload CSV format only");
            }

            $link = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            $db = mysql_select_db($mysql_db, $link) or die('Could not select database: ' . $mysql_db);

            $handle = fopen($fileName,"r");

            $i = 0;

            while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false){
                $playlist_id = $fileop[0];
                $playlist_name = $fileop[1];
                $playlist_description = $fileop[2];
                $playlist_shortcode = $fileop[3];

                $song_id = $fileop[4];
                $list_order = $fileop[5];
                $playlist_name = $fileop[6];
                $mp3 = $fileop[7];
                $ogg = $fileop[8];
                $title = $fileop[9];
                $buy = $fileop[10];
                $buyy = $fileop[11];
                $buyyy = $fileop[12];
                $price = $fileop[13];
                $cover = $fileop[14];
                $duration = $fileop[15];
                $artist = $fileop[16];
                $total_votes = $fileop[17];
                $song_shortcode = $fileop[18];
                $song_slug = $fileop[19];

                $rate_id = $fileop[20];
                $song_id = $fileop[21];
                $rating_value = $fileop[22];
                $user_ip = $fileop[23];

                if($i > 0){
                    $playlist_insert = "Insert Into wp_foo_playlists(playlist_id,playlist_name,playlist_description,playlist_shortcode) Value('$playlist_id','$playlist_name','$playlist_description','$playlist_shortcode')";
                    mysql_query($playlist_insert);

                    $song_insert = "Insert Into wp_foo_songs(song_id,list_order,splaylist_name,mp3,ogg,title,buy,buyy,buyyy,price,cover,duration,artist,total_votes,song_shortcode,song_slug) Value('$song_id','$list_order','$playlist_name','$mp3','$ogg','$title','$buy','$buyy','$buyyy','$price','$cover','$duration','$artist','$total_votes','$song_shortcode','$song_slug')";
                    mysql_query($song_insert);

                    $rate_insert = "Insert Into wp_foo_rating(rate_id,rsong_id,rating_value,user_ip) Value('$rate_id','1','$rating_value','$user_ip')";
                    mysql_query($rate_insert);
                }
                $i++;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
```

To ignore the first row from csv file i am using this coindtion

```
$i = 0;
if($i > 0){
    // Insert Queries
}
$i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to split the file into three files somehow if you want to use load data infile.

Alternatively, build an import routine in PHP to do exactly what you want

Comment: can you give me idea how can i split the file

Comment: this depends on how you create the file, can you give an example of how you include the data from the three tables into one file?

Comment: OK I understand now. Based on what you have provided, I think my original answer is correct. You either need to export as three separate files that represent the table structure so you can use the LOAD DATA INFILE method, or you need to a write a custom import handler that reads your input file line by line and builds the insert SQL for each table and runs the three insert queries.